# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to run this code, to download miniImagenet dataset but I keep getting the error "UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.". I have tried all the possible solutions posted in different platforms but none seems to be solving this error.
Please help.

```
            pickle_file = os.path.join(self.root, 'mini-imagenet-cache-' + mode + '.pkl')
        try:
            if not self._check_exists() and download:
                print('Downloading mini-ImageNet --', mode)
                download_pkl(google_drive_file_id, self.root, mode)
            with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
                self.data = pickle.load(f)
        except pickle.UnpicklingError:
            if not self._check_exists() and download:
                print('Download failed. Re-trying mini-ImageNet --', mode)
                download_file(dropbox_file_link, pickle_file)
            with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
                self.data = pickle.load(f)

        self.x = torch.from_numpy(self.data["image_data"]).permute(0, 3, 1, 2).float()
        self.y = np.ones(len(self.x))

        # TODO Remove index_classes from here
        self.class_idx = index_classes(self.data['class_dict'].keys())
        for class_name, idxs in self.data['class_dict'].items():
            for idx in idxs:
                self.y[idx] = self.class_idx[class_name]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = self.x[idx]
        if self.transform:
            data = self.transform(data)
        return data, self.y[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def _check_exists(self):
        return os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.root, 'mini-imagenet-cache-' + self.mode + '.pkl'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mi = MiniImagenet(root='./data', download=True)
    __import__('pdb').set_trace()
```

Comment: Was the pickled file made with a different version of Python that the one you are using?

Comment: or if file is incomplete/corrupted... do you have md5 hash of the original file to check if your copy is good?

Comment: @JohnGordon Its the same version of python

Comment: The code downloads the miniImagenet datset then gives the error. I don't have the md5 hash of the original file to check. I thought it should download the file anyway even if its corrupted or has got issues

Comment: It’s also good to keep in mind that unpickling untrusted files can expose you to an arbitrary code vulnerability. The Python docs have a big red box warning on the major security risks of using Python’s built-in pickling and unpickling functionality: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html